# MSAL + Angular Acquire token locally very slow

Tags: angular, token, openid, azure-ad-msal

I have searched high and low for an answer for this and cannot find a solution.
When running locally it makes a call to .well-known/openid-configuration for every api call made on the page and takes about 5 seconds each. Basically looks like it is trying to renew token before every call instead of using cached token. This is making development very slow and tedious. All of the compiled versions in Angular 7 work as expected.

Currently following documentation from https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/msal-angular

Comment: Found answer. Local env scopes were incorrect.

Comment: I don't suppose you could expand on that?